# how to apply a function to each group?

Tags: f#

I need to apply a function to each group represented by `(<seq>)` in the below code, but have the function treat each group as new data. So the function would reset after it has iterated through each group and then output the newly transformed groups.

```
let datafilter =
        datacsv
        |> List.groupBy (fun row -> row.Class,row.Room)
        |> List.iter (fun ((class,room),rows) -> func rows )

(* Outputs [((112, 1), <seq>); ((113, 2), <seq>); ((114, 3), <seq>);
       ((115, 4), <seq>); ((116, 5), <seq>); ((117, 6), <seq>);
       ((118, 7), <seq>); ((119, 8), <seq>); ((120, 9), <seq>);
       ((121, 10), <seq>); ((122, 11), <seq>); ((123, 12), <seq>)]  *)

type RoomAssignment = 
    { Class : int
      Room : int
      Date : DateTime
      People : int }
```

`func` is a random function. Error results when I run code:

```
TermStructure.fsx(96,46): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'unit'    
but here has type
    'RoomAssignment list'
```

Comment: Have you tried `List.iter`?

Comment: `Seq.iter` then?

Comment: Have updated question accordingly to make more sense and to see that I tried something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say what the `func` function is supposed to be doing, but judging from the error you get, it looks like it produces a list of `RoomAssignment` values. If you want to collect the results and have one result for each group, you probably need `map` rather than `iter`:

```
let datafilter =
  datacsv
  |> List.groupBy (fun row -> row.Class, row.Room)
  |> List.map (fun ((class,room),rows) -> func rows)
```

If you replace `func` with `Seq.length` (for example), then this will return the number of rows in each group (as defined by a pair of class and room).

It is difficult to give a more useful answer without having a full reproducible code snippet, but hopefully this will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: One might add the alternative resolution to the error, assuming that `List.iter` is indeed desired, is to replace `func rows` with `func rows |> ignore`.  It does not seem likely that this is the desired solution, however.

Comment: I suggest this question be closed because it is not clear to everyone what I am asking, and I have solved the issue using code that has nothing to do with the code in question. Thus, this question is pointless.

Comment: @JohnLaw I don't like this idea, there is a good answer already - it's unfair to close the Q after all.